# JavaScript: Call from outside (without var-definition)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, click, datatables, var

In my local test-area and as a standalone-script I use this

```
$(document).ready( function () {
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
"oTableTools": {
"sRowSelect": "single"
}
} );
```

and something like this

```
oTable.$('tr').click(function ()
```

to capture the ID of the first column in **[DataTables](http://datatables.net/)**. This works fine! BUT with the **[tablepress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/)**-plugin for **WordPress**, which is basically using *DataTables*, I cannot add (in this case) **"oTable = "** to the relating table I whish. This is really odd.

The only way is to change the "core" of the plugin, but that's nasty. So I have to place the 2nd part somewhere else on the page (which is no problem). Is there any other way to get the click on the table? Something like:

```
$('#example tr').click(function ()
```

I hope there is an easy and simple way like this ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#example').dataTable( {
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
"oTableTools": {
"sRowSelect": "single"
}
} );
```

and

```
$('#example tr').click(function () {
var data = $('#example').dataTable().fnGetData( this );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is some attribute in tbody tag of datatables
for example

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
```

you can check if your tables have these attr too, if so you can select like this

```
$('#example tbody[role="alert"] tr').click(function (){});
```

you can also use this

```
var oTable2 = $('#example').dataTable();
$('tr',oTable2).click(function ()
```

Comment: Hello @h0mayun, this doesn't work. There is no general tbody-attribute. Even if I take the table-id like `$('#example table[id="example"] tr').click(function` it's not working.